# fseek function is not working after fopen(argv[1], "ab")

Tags: c, file, fopen, fseek

When I opened the file with "wb" option, fseek worked well.
But fseek function is not working well after fopen(argv[1], "ab").

Is there any problem in my code?

Here is the code.

```
student.h
struct student {
  int id;
};

main.c
#define START_ID 1201001
struct student rec;
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if(fp==NULL) {
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "wb");
} else {
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen(argv[1], "ab");
}
fseek(fp, (rec.id-START_ID)*sizeof(sec), SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `fseek` is ***not supposed to work*** when a file is opened with the `"a"` attribute. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/):

> append: Open file for output at the end of a file. Output operations
>   always write data at the end of the file, expanding it. Repositioning
>   operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) are ignored. The file is created
>   if it does not exist.

To get round the problem, try using the `"a+"` attribute:

> append/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output) with
>   all output operations writing data at the end of the file.
>   Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) affects the next
>   input operations, but output operations move the position back to the
>   end of file. The file is created if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The mode argument points to a string. 
If the string is one of the following (as mentioned below), the file shall be opened in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

> r or rb Open file for reading.
>
> w or wb Truncate to zero length or create file for writing.
>
> a or ab Append; open or create file for writing at end-of-file.
>
> r+ or rb+ or r+b Open file for update (reading and writing).
>
> w+ or wb+ or w+b Truncate to zero length or create file for update.
>
> a+ or ab+ or a+b Append; open or create file for update, writing at
>   end-of-file.

So when you use the flag `ab` you are saying that you want the file to be created / opened for writing at **end-of-file**. Hence you won't be able to use `fseek` for same reason.

> **Solution:**

Try using other flags (mentioned above) so that you can use `fseek`.

> **For more information refer**:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html